# Send Message aloha network omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I want to ask you a question about omnet++ . I am supposed to do an exercise on an aloha network . 
I have to send a message to a random host (node) but the message must go through the aloha server first . The problem is , when the Server tries to send the message an error occurs that says :"cannot send via an input gate "in" ". 
I 've tried to create an output gate on server.ned called "output out" . Then when I try to run the simulation I have an error that says "Gate aloha.server.out is not connected to a sibling or parent module". 
Does anybody know where do I specify the 'out' gate and how ? I am new to omnet++ and I ' ve also searched the documentation manual about gates but I cant find the solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a few things that need clarification.

1. Sending a message in **radio** system (like `Aloha`) is modeled in `OMNeT++` using `sendDirect()` method. It does not require any output gate. Reference: [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:direct-sending).
2. The `Aloha` example is very simple and it has the following limitations:

   - host does not receive messages, only server receives them,
   - hosts do not have any addresses.

To achieve your goal you should:

- introduce addresses of hosts,
- add a destination address filed in frame,
- add input gate with annotation `@directIn` in host,
- change behavior of the server - it should retransmit received message to every host,
- change behavior of the host - it should receive a message, check its address and process the message provided that the destination address is equal to its own address.

Comment: thank you for the response . I would like to ask if its possible for the server to send to just a random host (with uniform etc) and how can I accomplish that ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Server should obtain a list of all hosts, then choose one from this list and send received message towards this host using `sendDirect()`. Remember to add input gate in host.